# Calculating expectation of a random variable knowing expectation of a function of it

Tags: probability, random-variables, expectation

Let $X$ be a random variable taking values from $\mathbb{R}^+$. If $\mathbb{E}[a^{X}]$ is given for some positive constant $a$, then what can be said about $\mathbb{E}[X]$? I am particularly looking for some statement stronger than what Jensen's inequality suggests, *i.e.,* $\mathbb{E}[a^X] \ge a^{\mathbb{E}[X]}$.

Is it possible to calculate or bound $\mathbb{E}[X]$ if nothing is known about distribution of $X$?

Comment: If $X$ is a constant random variable, then your bound given by Jensen is the best you can do.  What else are you looking for?

Comment: What do you mean by "constant random variable"?

Comment: Are you given the _numerical value_ of $E[a^X]$ for a given number $a$, or do you know $E[a^X]$ as a function of $a$, $a \in \mathbb R^+$? If the latter, do you know the notion of the moment-generating function $E[e^{tX}]$ of $X$? Can it be adapted to your problem?

Comment: A random variable that takes exactly one value with probability 1.  (That is, a very boring random variable.)

Comment: @DilipSarwate: I just know $\mathbb{E}[a^X]$ for a specific positive constant $a$ and not as a function of $a$. I am kind of familiar with the concept of moment-generating function, but cannot see how it can be exploited to solve this problem.

Comment: @StephenMontgomery-Smith: Ah, I see. But $X$ is not necessarily a constant random variable.

Comment: @Ali yes, but it does provide an example to show that your Jensen argument cannot be improved without further assumptions on $x$.

Comment: @StephenMontgomery-Smith: Fair enough. Then, I better rephrase my question as what other information about $X$, except its density function, help attain a tighter bound for (or the exact value of) $\mathbb{E}[X]$?